# PayPal REST Subscriptions API not showing price in order summary

Tags: rest, paypal, recurring-billing

I am testing the PayPal REST API for subscriptions in the sandbox environment, and have noticed that, when going to the approval URL returned after creating an agreement, no price is shown under the order summary pane on the left of the page. A description is shown but no price/tax etc.

The plan id is passed to the call to create an agreement, which contains the information that I would expect to see as a user when approving the payment. Is this a bug or is there something that I am supposed to enable in the merchant account, or perhaps something additional that needs to be sent when creating the agreement? I've read other posts regarding this on stack overflow (although they predate the creation of the subscriptions REST API) talking about passing a transaction field, but this isn't valid in the subscriptions create agreement schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observations are (currently) correct. As REST API based Billing Plans are based on Express Checkout Recurring Payments, you're going to see a similar behavior. 
Right now, there are two options:

1. You populate the description with more agreement details.
2. You pass a regular description and make sure the customer is aware of the billing terms before your execute the agreement.

Going forward, we're likely going to include this info in some later updates. I'm following up with that to make sure a user story is filed for this.

Comment: What is the status on this? is there any way to actually show payment details using any of the APIs for recurring subscriptions?

Comment: Also, I'd like to display the terms and condition of the subscription.