# PayPal subscription: cost not shown at checkout?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am using the PayPal SDK for php. And I "think" everything is working. 
Create plan -> activate plan -> create agreement -> redirect user to agree -> execute agreement. done?

I find it very strange that when the user is redirected to PayPal, they can not see any price at all, they are just asked to agree. I have a setup fee, it's not displayed and a monthly recurring fee, it's not displayed either.
Am I doing something wrong?

Should PayPal not charge the setup fee once I execute the agreement? Or is there a final step that I have missed completely? (I can see in the developer console sandbox notifications that subscriptions are setup)

I also tried it live and it is the same way there, no price is displayed at all.

[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093117/paypal-rest-subscriptions-api-not-showing-price-in-order-summary

Comment: Please add your code so we can see what you are doing and how you are doing it.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this issue?, Because I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at this [issue on Github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/149#issuecomment-179780518) it's been around since 2014. You're not the first to encounter this issue. The issue is continued in [this issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/7) and then continued in [this issue](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/4)

Summary of comments: Paypal seems to be dead set for the last 4-5 years not to implement anything for unknown reasons.

The current status of working around the issue is: Put the details and the price in the description if you wish to display details of what they agree to.
Also make sure that the page that leads to the paypal page describes clearly what they agreeing to and which amount.

Comment: Hello Tschallacka ,I'm facing the same issue, Is there any solutions for this one now?

Comment: @TheBeast The issue is still open, you're facing it now, it's safe to say it's not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using REST API's and using this for subscription then don't add start_time in the request.